# remove all elements in array with .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

So I have an array of numbers, let's say `["1", "3", "2"]`

they correspond to values of the data-cardNumber attribute I've given to certain elements.

I want all elements with the data-cardNumber values in the array to be removed.

I tried doing this by iterating through the array and constructing a selector per each item in the array that calls `.remove()`, but that doesn't work.

I think the selector is too complex since it spans multiple strings.

**How can I iterate through the array and `.remove()` all elements with the data-cardNumber attribute whose values are in the array?**

Here is the code that I tried:

```
for(var i=0; i<swipedAwayCards.length; i++){
    $('[data-cardNumber="'+swipedAwayCards[i]'"]').remove();
    // i'm trying to construct a selector like [data-cardNumber="1"]
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's just a syntax error, which should have shown up in console: `$('[data-cardNumber="'+swipedAwayCards[i]+'"]')` you missed the final `+` , you shouldn't need `"` either: `$('[data-cardNumber='+swipedAwayCards[i]+']')`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I'm pretty sure the `"`s are necessary for it to be a valid _CSS_ selector; I don't know if _jQuery_ requires them, but it would be best practice to keep them

Comment: jQuery doesn't require them, but yes it's best to have them as it avoids other issues that could creep up (special characters in said attribute for example)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just a syntax error, which should have shown up in console:

```
$('[data-cardNumber="'+swipedAwayCards[i]+'"]')
```

(You missed the final `+` in your concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
$('[data-cardNumber="'+swipedAwayCards[i] + '"]').each(function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

This should work rather than doing a for loop since jquery already has the capability to iterate over all matches of a selector.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do either of the the Following

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i = 0 ; i< a.length; i++){
delete(a[i]); // This resets the value to undefined
}
```

which produces the following result

**[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]**

or

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b;
for(var i = 0 ; i< a.length; i++){
  b = a.pop();// This actually removes the Element from array and puts it in the variable b
}
```

Result: ** b = 1  At last as last element to be popped will be 1  and b = []**

Comment: You may want to re-read the question